# DynamoDB: multiple project on the DB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

we'd like to use DynamoDB for several application (each with multiple tables). Is there any way how to group tables together (something like folders)? I tried to tag a tables, but when I created resource group I didn't see dynamoDB under resource types. Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, there is no approach to organize the tables in AWS Console. In most of the cases, prefixes are used to keep the tables together in the list.

e.g:

- prod_users
- prod_tenants
- stag_users
- stag_tenants

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: This looks correct, but it's still annoying not to be able organize with schemas or folders